# Android LinearLayout place elements in the middle with landscape and portrait mode

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

My layout contains three buttons, one `EditText` field and one button. I want to place the three buttons in one row, but in the center (horizontal) of the screen. The `EditText` field should be below the buttons and below the `EditText` field, there should be one button.

Here is my layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/blueAct"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="100.0dip"
    android:paddingLeft="10.0dip"
    android:paddingRight="10.0dip"
    android:paddingTop="100.0dip" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="4.0dip"
        android:paddingLeft="100.0dip"
        android:paddingRight="100.0dip"
        android:paddingTop="5.0dip" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/buttonGreen"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginRight="4.0dip"
            android:background="@drawable/green_button"
            android:contentDescription="@string/green" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/buttonRed"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginRight="4.0dip"
            android:background="@drawable/red_button"
            android:contentDescription="@string/red" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/buttonBlue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginRight="4.0dip"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_button"
            android:contentDescription="@string/blue" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/phone_code"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/phone_code"
        android:paddingTop="100.0dip"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textColorHint="@color/white" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:background="@color/orangeAct"
        android:onClick="searchUsers"
        android:paddingTop="100.0dip"
        android:text="@string/button_go"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now the problem is, that the three buttons are not in the center if the user changes from portrait to landscape mode.
How is it possible to make this 'responsive', without creating a separate layout file for landscape mode?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use padding on your horizontal LinearLayout to center the views. Instead you can add views before and after that expand to fill the remaining space.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonGreen"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ... />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonRed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ... />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonBlue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ... />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@mipmap/background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/homemain124"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/paneltamrin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="something"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:id="@+id/top1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/textcorner"
            android:layout_below="@+id/top1"
            android:text="something"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:id="@+id/top2"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/top2"
            android:text="APPLIED BY"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:id="@+id/top3"
            android:textColor="#fff"

            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/top3"

            android:text="COURT OF JUSTICE IN INDIA"
            android:id="@+id/top4"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textStyle="bold"

            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>






    </RelativeLayout>



    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/paneltamrin2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="220dp"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/book1"
            android:id="@+id/image1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"

            />



        </RelativeLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/paneltamrin3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="READ NOW"
            android:textColor="#fff"

            android:lineSpacingExtra="10dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"

            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/buttonorder"

            android:padding="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"

            android:background="@drawable/orderbutton"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
        <TextView

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttonorder"

            android:text="something"/>




        </RelativeLayout>




    </LinearLayout>
```

Linear layout added for 3 relative layouts